# V4 onEnter alternative, fetch before render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

In react-router v4, `onEnter` was removed because of the new organization of the project, I get it.

But I used it to fetch data from the server before rendering the component.

It was suggested to use `componentDidMount` and fetch form there, this would work, but I use redux, and the code inside `map(State|Dispatch)ToProps` function expect the store to be up.

My current solution is to put some if's to check if it has data, and render empty, but that does not look to good...

Is there any documentation/example that I can see about using react-router v4 with redux?

Comment: This seems to have disappeared now, but was in an old commit: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/7f6706dab4827afc1c26a58418f8ef8c8ab40125/website/examples/Redux.js. From this it seems that since we're handing the location state and location_change event ourselves. Somewhere downstream from ``<Router>``'s ``onChange`` is where the server fetch would probably go now.

Comment: I am a bit lost.

V4 is a great update, in one side it made my code, smaller smarter and more organized.
But there isnt many info.
And this problems are freaking me out

Comment: a discussion about the problem here : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3854